# Linux: Diff Two Directories?

Tags: linux

I want to perform a diff between two directories and see what files (if any) have changed.  Is there an easy way to do this? I've tried to use `diff` but it seems to only show the file-content differences.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

EDIT: This has been asked and answered before: [Different files of two directories](https://serverfault.com/questions/79226/different-files-of-two-directories).  I just typed "diff directory" in the search box, and there it was.

```
$ diff -rq DIR1 DIR2
```

Here are the details:

```
$ diff --help
[...]
-q  --brief  Output only whether files differ.
[...]
-r  --recursive  Recursively compare any subdirectories found.
[...]
```

Answer (score 3):

rsync -n (dry run) will do what you need. check rsync --help output for any other options that you may find useful when searching for changes. i wouldn't use diff to do this.

edit: including example

```
cia@pinkpony:~$ rsync -nric  dev2/py/lib/sysami/ dev/py/lib/sysami/
>fcsT...... __init__.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a graphical difference tool such as:

- KDiff
- Meld
- GTKDiff
- Kompare
- etc.

Just type "diff" in your package manager.